# Ignore .pyc files in git repository

Tags: python, git

How can I ignore `.pyc` files in git?

If I put it in `.gitignore` it doesn't work. I need them to be untracked and not checked for commits.

Comment: .gitignore should work. Can you provide a copy of the lines you have put in .gitignore to attempt to solve this problem?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Put it in `.gitignore`. But from the `gitignore(5)` man page:

> ```
>   ·   If the pattern does not contain a slash /, git treats it as a shell
>        glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative
>        to the location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of
>        the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).
>
>   ·   Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for
>        consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in
>        the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example,
>        "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not
>        "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or
>        "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".
> ```

So, either specify the full path to the appropriate `*.pyc` entry, or put it in a `.gitignore` file in any of the directories leading from the repository root (inclusive).

Comment: Thanks Godsmit, so you're saying on the root directory where my `main.py` is I can just put a `.gitignore` there? and inside is `*.pyc` and it will ignore all `.pyc` files ANYWHERE even if it's inside in more directories?

Answer (score 334):

You should add a line with:

```
*.pyc
```

to the `.gitignore` file in the root folder of your git repository tree right after repository initialization.

As *ralphtheninja* said, if you forgot to to do it beforehand, if you just add the line to the `.gitignore` file, all previously committed `.pyc` files will still be tracked, so you'll need to remove them from the repository.

If you are on a Linux system (or "parents&sons" like a MacOSX), you can quickly do it with just this one line command that you need to execute from the root of the repository:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec git rm -f "{}" \;
```

This just means:

> *starting from the directory i'm currently in, find all files whose
>   name ends with extension `.pyc`, and pass file name to the command `git rm -f`*

After `*.pyc` files deletion from git as tracked files, commit this change to the repository, and then you can finally add the `*.pyc` line to the `.gitignore` file.

*(adapted from http://yuji.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/git-remove-all-pyc/)*

Comment: Alternatively, just to remove the files from git and from your local machine, you can just do `git rm --cached *.pyc` from the top level directory. Got it from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/wrxwog/why-not-to-commit-pyc-files-into-git-and-how-to-fix-if-you-already-did)

Comment: I have it exist but once you commit the .pyc files it gets tracked by git anyway, you should delete them first and commit in case you have them in repository

Answer (score 97):

You have probably added them to the repository before putting `*.pyc` in `.gitignore`.
First remove them from the repository.

Answer (score 10):

i try to use the sentence of a prior post and don't work recursively, then read some help and get this line:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec git rm -f "{}" \;
```

p.d. is necessary to add *.pyc in .gitignore file to maintain git clean

```
echo "*.pyc" >> .gitignore
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to ignore '.pyc' files globally (i.e. if you do not want to add the line to .gitignore file in every git directory), try the following:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig 
[core]
    excludesFile = ~/.gitignore
$ cat ~/.gitignore
**/*.pyc
```

[Reference]
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

- Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by core.excludesFile in the user’s ~/.gitconfig.
- A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

Answer (score 2):

if you have committed in the repo, just

1. go to the folder `/__pycache__`,
2. delete all of them (no worries, they are temporary files and generated repeatedly)
3. have a new commit, such as 'update gitignore'
4. you are done! **`.pyc` will not appear again.**

Comment: Yeah, you firstly need put *.pyc in /.gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Enrico for the answer.

Note if you're using virtualenv you will have several more `.pyc` files within the directory you're currently in, which will be captured by his find command.

For example:

```
./app.pyc
./lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
./lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
./lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
./lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/__init__.pyc
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/__init__.pyc
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/api.pyc
```

I suppose it's harmless to remove all the files, but if you only want to remove the `.pyc` files in your main directory, then just do

`find "*.pyc" -exec git rm -f "{}" \;`

This will remove just the `app.pyc` file from the git repository.